# How do I add a border after inserting an image or a hyperlink on xlswriter

Tags: django-views, xlsxwriter

I am using xlswriter for Django. I am not sure how to add a full border after I have inserted an image or a hyperlink. Keep in mind both codes are in a loop.

```
 #set cell border format
 full_border = workbook.add_format(
     {
         'border': 1, #border size
         'border_color': '#000000' #color black
     }
 )


 #for the rest of the table
 row = 4
 column = 1

 for prod in users_fav_products:

    image_url = prod.product.image
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url).read()
    image_name = f'favoriteproduct{row}'
    file = open(image_name, "wb")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    worksheet.insert_image(
        row,
        column,
        image_name,
        {
            'x_scale': 0.5,
            'y_scale': 0.5,
            'x_offset': 5,
            'y_offset': 5,
            'positioning': 1,
            'border': 1,  # border size
            'border_color': '#000000'  # color black
        }
    )
    worksheet.write_url(row, 2,  prod.product.link, string=prod.product.name)
    worksheet.write(row, 3, prod.product.reviews, full_border)
    worksheet.write(row, 4, prod.product.price, full_border)
    row +=1
```

So How to add a full border to the cell after the image is inserted?

```
        worksheet.insert_image(
        row,
        column,
        image_name,
        {
            'x_scale': 0.5,
            'y_scale': 0.5,
            'x_offset': 5,
            'y_offset': 5,
            'positioning': 1,
            'border': 1,  # border size
            'border_color': '#000000'  # color black
        }
    )
```

And how to add a full border to the cell after inserting a link?

```
worksheet.write_url(row, 2,  prod.product.link, string=prod.product.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation to the first part of your question, you can't format the border of an image with XlsxWriter.

In relation to the second part of the question, you can add a border around hyperlink cell like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hyperlink.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the column for clarity.
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 30)

# Add a sample alternative link format.
link_format = workbook.add_format({
    'font_color': 'blue',
    'underline': 1,
    'border': 1,
})

# Write the link.
worksheet.write_url('B2', 'http://www.python.org/', link_format)

# Write the link with a string alternative.
worksheet.write_url('B3', 'http://www.python.org/', link_format, "String 1")

# Same as the previous example with named arguments.
worksheet.write_url('B4', 'http://www.python.org/', string="String 2", cell_format=link_format)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

See the docs on [worksheet.write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url).

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesnt solve that problem fully. The hyperlink has no string in it.  thats why i was stuck with this worksheet.write_url(row, 2,  prod.product.link, string=prod.product.name)

Comment: You can just add the format, or string, as an additional parameter. See my updated response.

Comment: solved the image problem!!  By adding this code:  worksheet.write(row, column, None, full_border)  in the loop before the code that inserts the image.